# Stellar Cross-Border Payments (Do SEP-38 is Mandatory to Implement)

Tags: stellar-core, stellar-sdk, stellar-laboratory, stellar.toml

We are implementing cross border payments using stellar SEP 31 protocol. Looking out for a guidance on SEP 38 that gives us details about the quotes for an on/off stellar asset.

As you know, SEP 38 is in draft status and our team is thinking is there any chance we could bypass it.

If yes, would anyone had experience implementing it before and what endpoint we need to expose on SEP 31 to accommodate SEP 38.

Your Help would be highly appreciated.